# Python Elements Not Working Once Put in Function

Tags: python, function, loops

```
sample_array = [[[1.25], [1.10]], [[-1.09], [1.29]], [[1.34], [-1.34]], [[-1.12], [1.34]], [[-1.03], [-1.31]], [[-1.10], [-1.35]]]
```

When I put it in the following code it does work to pull the first element from each subset which is what I'm trying to do

```
for i in range(len(sample_array)):
    c = sample_array[i][0][0]
    d = initializedList.append(c)
    i+=1
```

However when I add in a function it does not work.

```
def my_function(b):
    initializedList = []
    for i in range(len(b)):
        c = b[i][0][0]
        d = initializedList.append(c)
        i+=1
    return d
```

Comment: `for i in range(len(b))` already iterates for all values of `i` from 0, 1, 2, ..., b-1. The `i += 1` inside the loop is causing it to behave unexpectedly.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
def my_function(b):
    initializedList = []
    for i in range(len(b)):
        c = b[i][0][0]
        initializedList.append(c)
        # i+=1
    return initializedList 


sample_array = [[[1.25], [1.10]], [[-1.09], [1.29]], [[1.34], [-1.34]], [[-1.12], [1.34]], [[-1.03], [-1.31]], [[-1.10], [-1.35]]]


print(my_function(sample_array))
```

Output:

```
[1.25, -1.09, 1.34, -1.12, -1.03, -1.1]
```